# This ValueListenableBuilder widget cannot be marked as needing to build

Tags: flutter

in simple part of my application i defined this value as `ValueNotifier`:

```
final ValueNotifier<List<MediaDropDownStructure>> _mediaFoldersList = ValueNotifier<List<MediaDropDownStructure>>([]);
```

i used this variable inside `DropDownBottom` items to fill them and create manu and i fill that by this code inside `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder<List<MediaModel>>(
    stream: _globalBloc.storageMediaBloc.imagesMedia$,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator( ),
        );
      }
      final List<MediaModel> _allImages = snapshot.data;
      _mediaFoldersList.value = _allImages.map( (image) => MediaDropDownStructure( image.folder, image.folder ) ).toList();

      final MediaModel _all = _allImages[0];
      return GridView.builder(

      ...
```

and i use that inside `DropDownBotton` like with:

```
child: ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: _mediaFoldersList,
    builder: (context, List<MediaDropDownStructure> items,child)=>DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton<MediaDropDownStructure>(
        value: _chooseFolderName.value,
        hint: Text("please choose",style: AppTheme.of(context).caption(),),
        items: items.map((MediaDropDownStructure menuItem) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<MediaDropDownStructure>(
            value: menuItem,
            child: Text(menuItem.folderPath),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (_) {},
      ),
    ),
),
```

and i get this error:

```
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for ValueNotifier<List<MediaDropDownStructure>>:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This ValueListenableBuilder<List<MediaDropDownStructure>> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: ValueListenableBuilder<List<MediaDropDownStructure>>
  dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#2b62a]]
  state: _ValueListenableBuilderState<List<MediaDropDownStructure>>#6c134
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: StreamBuilder<List<MediaModel>>
  dirty
  state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<MediaModel>, AsyncSnapshot<List<MediaModel>>>#cbf2d
```

Comment: can you add more details like where you are filling _mediaFoldersList and how you use it to build dropdown.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya my post and code updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem is that while streambuilder is building its state meanwhile _mediaFoldersList's value also change, so it will also start to build ValueListenableBuilder and it is creating issue because two builder can not build together.

To solve it you can change _mediaFoldersList's value after 1 microsecond, so streambuilder builder complete it's build method and then ValueListenableBuilder can build.

cratemethod like below.

```
 changevaluenotifiervalue(_allImages) async {

    await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1));
  _mediaFoldersList.value = _allImages.map( (image) => MediaDropDownStructure( image.folder, image.folder ) ).toList();

  }
```

call this method where you are changing its value.

```
final List<MediaModel> _allImages = snapshot.data;
      //_mediaFoldersList.value = _allImages.map( (image) => MediaDropDownStructure( image.folder, image.folder ) ).toList();  //commented 
  changevaluenotifiervalue(_allImages);  // added
  final MediaModel _all = _allImages[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, problem solved. i learnt new tips in flutter, is any another best solution about this issue?

Comment: Your Welcome!. i tried to find but i didn't get any.